# Hierarquia de requisições com Await

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Seguinte... eu preciso fazer uma hierarquia de requisições que dependem entre si.

Fiz toda a estrutura, porém quando eu rodo o código eles são resolvidos de forma assíncrona, sem esperar a resolução de uma requisição para seguir o código logo abaixo.

Segue como está a estrutura:

Esta é a requisição onde é feito
[image: requisicao]

Este é o método no serviço:
[image: servico]

Depois do SyncDevices que se inicia a Hierarquia de requisições:
[image: syncdevices]

E depois do fetchHeaders tem varias outras assim como no SyncDevices, uma dependendo da outra e sendo resolvidas uma depois da outra. Mas preciso resolver a função TryRecconectAccount pois tendo a resposta dela eu posso remover o loading na tela.

Se alguem tiver alguma idéia do que posso fazer...
Obrigado

Comment: Acho que a palavra correta seria "assíncrona". :D

Comment: Não coloque código como imagem. Em vez disso coloque como texto formatando de forma apropriada através do editor na pergunta. Isso permite que alguem consiga reproduzir o código que você tem de forma mais facilitada. O ideal seria até vocẽ criar um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) do problema.

Answer (score 3):

Esse não é um exemplo verificável, então não sei se isso irá bastar, mas consigo ver alguns problemas no seu código.

A função `tryReconnectAccount`, apesar de ser assíncrona, não espera o retorno de `this.syncDevicesFeatures`, ela apenas chama a função e imediatamente retorna `undefined` (toda função sem retorno explicito retorna undefined) antes que `syncDevicesFeatures` termine de executar.

Se `syncDevicesFeatures` retornar uma promise (ou for async), você poderia usar

```
 async tryReconnectAccount(data, headers, props, account) {
     return await this.syncDevicesFeatures(data, headers, props, account);
 }
```

Na verdade não estou vendo razão para tryReconnectAccount existir, visto que ela apenas invoca syncDevicesFeatures com os mesmos parâmetros.

Comment: Obrigado pela moral. O `tryReconnectAccount` foi feito para testes e esqueci de apagar :D. Mas o `syncDevicesFeatures` sendo retornado desta forma com o await ele tbm espera as demais funcoes sendo chamadas dentro dele?